# Know someone who can answer? Share list broken

Tags: support, sharing

The list has several empty strings in it for me right now:
[image]

Comment: An Adblock rule is now affecting the sprite sheet used to make the left end of the StackExchange header bar, causing it to appear blank.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No it's not - it's a new AdBlock filter that apparently pushed recently:

```
[title="Share with others"],
[title="Submit this post on newsvine.com."],
[title="Submit this post on reddit.com."],
[title="Submit to Digg"],
[title="Subscribe by Facebook"],
[title="Subscribe by Twitter"],
[title="Thumb this up at StumbleUpon"],
[title="Tweet This"],
[title="Yahoo! Buzz"],
a[href="http://www.addtoany.com/share_save"],
a[href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php"],
a[href^="http://twitter.com/share?text="],
a[href^="http://twitter.com/share?url="],
a[href^="http://twitthis.com/twit?url"],
a[href^="http://vk.com/share.php?url="],
a[href^="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?"],
a[href^="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="],
a[href^="http://www.feedburner.com/fb/a/emailverifySubmit?"],
a[href^="http://www.sharethis.com/share/?publisher="],
a[href^="https://plus.google.com/share?url="] {
    display: none;
}
```

Talk about overkill...

Comment: ...and this is why I have Stack Overflow (and the network) whitelisted on ABP - to avoid weird stuff like this from affecting me.

Comment: ...and this is why I don't use things like ABP at all.

Answer (score 5):

Disable [Adblock Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb) (or any other ad blocker plugin), use different profile (e.g. *Incognito* in Chrome) or use different web browser.

You can also add Stack Exchange sites into Whitelisted domain list.

> You can add a domain either via the Adblock Plus icon in the address bar or by typing the domain (not a URL) in the box and clicking the "Add domain" button.