# Too many commas in the social network share text

Tags: bug, status-declined, share-this

The bug appears, with my account, in every post that haven't any answer yet.
At the bottom just above the "Your Answer" section, I always see:

> Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email,
>   , , or .

In my mind, there should be a link to share to Twitter, Facebook, or other social networks, but I'm on any of these.

Comment: Are you running an ad blocker? Any extensions? What happens when you disable them?

Comment: You have a social media blocker I think...

Comment: @Oded You're right, it comes from Adblock Plus, by disabling it all is normal. But, this doesn't bother my: I wanted to signal a bug, is this the correct way to do this ?

Comment: This is how you report a bug, but there is no bug with SE.

Comment: @Luuklag it's not really about wording. The wording is just fine, the bug is that some words just disappear.

Comment: Here is another related post: [Know someone who can answer? Share list broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214355) Other [questions linke there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/214355) seem to be about the same problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This isn't a bug we can fix, given you are running an ad blocker that is blocking the bits you are missing.

Either the ad blocker needs to fix its blocking lists, or you need to stop using it ;)

Comment: I'm no adblock expert, but isn't there a whitelist you can get yourselves on that would allow such things?

Comment: @James - yeah. Free for "small" sites, whatever they company behind it deems as "small". If one doesn't fall under that (we don't), it isn't so free...

Comment: @James - see here: https://adblockplus.org/en/acceptable-ads-agreements "Whitelisting is free for all small- and medium websites and blogs."

Comment: Ah so no then. I love their wording, almost reads like Robin Hood set it up.

Comment: Or the ad blocker should learn to remove commas between blocked elements as well.