# Can the "Sponsored by AWS" message be made smaller (less annoying)?

Tags: feature-request, design, advertising, responsive-design, sponsored-sites

Looking at Ask Ubuntu, the "Sponsored by AWS" is... large on mobile. For reference, this is how it would look on an iPhone 12 (I'm using device emulation for the screenshots hence why I'm signed out, but the "Sponsored by AWS" is still just as in my face on a real mobile device).

Ask Ubuntu:

[image]

I'm mostly asking for this because I noticed on Ask Ubuntu, but *I'd like this for other sites with this sponsorship-notice*. For example, [Server Fault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOsaAl.png) and [Web Applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxgBMl.png)

I'll quote [the AWS sponsor announcement for Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/20063/aws-will-be-sponsoring-ask-ubuntu/20068), as that is how I noticed this (by pure chance, I haven't checked other sponsored sites on mobile recently apparently)

> What else changes?
> Not a thing! Borrowing from [the original MSE announcement on sponsorships](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307861/site-sponsorships-bringing-resources-back-to-stack-exchange):
>
> > First — sponsors do not own these Q&A sites. Sponsors work alongside our communities who ultimately build these sites. Communities ask the questions; communities create the tags; communities conduct elections as they do now, and we are not renaming our current sites like a garish sport stadium to the highest bidder. Any ads a sponsor submits still have go through our crazy-strict ad editorial process… as it has always been. Companies do not have access to personal data, and all Q&A content remains irrevocably licensed under Creative Commons for sharing and attribution.
>
> Sponsorships are a tool that our clients can use to let folks who could be interested in their products know about them in a non-intrusive way.

So... um... having "SPONSORED BY AWS" as the first thing on the page below the page name (and the menu bar) doesn't exactly seem "non-intrusive" to me. It seems more like a banner ad.

Of course, I have a proposed solution: make the sponsor on the same line as the site name. This is what is done on "desktop". The sponsor is still displayed, but it doesn't look like an in-my-face banner ad. Considering the sponsor adds no useful information to me (when viewing the page, specifically), it doesn't need a dedicated line on the page prominently displaying it.

Something like this, but with the big orange box shorter (I made this quickly in paint.net)

[image]

---

Some of y'all might notice [I originally posted this on Ask Ubuntu Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/20068/1438484). Turns out this affects several sites (three I've seen, maybe more?), so that is why it goes here.

Comment: I don't find it too big, it is fine considering the narrow view.

Comment: Also, if it affects more sites **please mention which sites exactly**, as it is currently written, it's specific to one site and off topic here.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I don’t know all of them, but at least the six at the bottom of [the table in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380648/1081494), maybe more. But six is enough that I felt it isn’t just Ask Ubuntu and should go to MSE. I mentioned two others in the Q, but I can add more in the morning if you want (it is evening where I am). Of course, if you disagree, go ahead and downvote. I won’t be offended, and design requests are (almost?) always subjective

Comment: Here's a list: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341663/282094, but [Auth0](https://security.stackexchange.com) is the biggest.

Comment: @Rob Auth0  appears to be the same as AWS, but my eyes aren't that sharp. Anyway if this question is about **all** sponsored sites it should be edited to say this. It is too radical change so not editing it myself and leaving the close vote in place.

Comment: Thanks for the list. My main concern is AWS (of the sponsored sites I’m mostly active on AU), so I’ll limit the scope of this request to “any SE site sponsored be AWS”

Comment: I agree with @Shadow that the sponsor message is not very big. Besides, why are you browsing AU on a phone? You should be using Ubuntu for that! (only half kidding, for solving your own issues/asking questions/answering it would make sense to have the actual OS at hand, only maybe for reviews or for "Ubuntu completely broke" issues browsing from a phone would be the better option)

Comment: @Rob totally not relevant, it's about mobile view. There is already something else, called "responsive view" in place, and it's working fine. (In most pages, some still don't have it, but homepage of all sites do have it.)

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsite-sponsorship%5D - you can see the size here: https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3470/67377

Comment: Whether the ad is big or not, it's very annoying how close it is to the logo. I keep clicking on it by mistake when all I want is to click on the logo to go back on the homepage.